# Code formatting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, `df`, for which I want to change the order of some columns. I have been struggling with using the multi index.

Running the command `df.columns`, I get the following output:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday'], ['Margin $', 'Margin %', 'Sales -GST $', 'entity']],
           labels=[[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]],
           names=['DayOfWeek', None])
```

The only columns that are visible in `df` are `['Margin %', 'Sales -GST $']`, however I'd like them to be in the opposite order, `['Sales -GST $', 'Margin %']`.

If someone could help me out that would be great.

Comment: For the second level of the column index I was hoping to change the order from;['Margin %' ,'Sales -GST $'] to ['Sales -GST $', 'Margin %' ]

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! I have edited your question to format the code sections for readability. I have also taken the liberty of removing the request for a guide, as requests for off-site resources are off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 1):

You can swap the order of your multiindex by using the `swaplevel` index method.

```
df.index.swaplevel()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change the order by changing the order of indexes while creating multi index.

For example seeing your output you might have created multi indexes as shown below.
arrays = [np.array(['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday']),
          np.array(['Margin $', 'Margin %', 'Sales -GST $', 'entity'])]

In the above you can change the order according to your needs.

Here is quick link for reference.
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html